# SEM Model Comparisons

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, model-comparison

I am learning/applying SEM to survey data in a behavioural study. I am comparing two structural models - one is simply having all the latent explanatory variables pointing to the response latent variable:  LV1~ LV2 + LV3 + LV4 + LV5... 
In the other model, I have multiple regression equations based on some hypothesised relationships: e.g. LV1~LV2+LV3; LV3~LV4+LV5

It turns out that the model fits are very similar (and acceptable), but in the first model, regression results show that almost all the coefficients are not significant. On the other hand, the second model (with multiple regression equations) found most coefficients significant.

I'd like to report that the second model is a better one than the first one, given that the coefficients are significant. Can I actually say that given that the model fits are pretty much the same?

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: Which coefficients in the first model are significant? What's your (unweighted) sample size? Are you using proper variance estimation with the survey data if you are using the weights?

Comment: Actually, none of the regression coefficients in the first model are significant. Most of the regression coefficients in the second model are significant. I am using DWLS estimator in the lavaan pacakge since most of my survey data are in 5-point likert scales. There are close to 600 observations.

Comment: Well, if e.g. LV3 is highly correlated with LV4 and LV5, then p values of LV3, LV4 and LV5 in the single equation regression might be high due to the induced multicollinearity. Did you check all these correlations between regressors?

Comment: Also make sure you look at modification indices from the first model. You may see (should see) high indices for relationships between LV3-5.